# segmentation fault in SSE when -O3 is on

Tags: c++, c, performance, gcc, sse

I found a very strange behaviour when using gcc's ***-O3*** or ***-O2***  option.

When my program is running under debug mode (***-g***), it is fine; but it raises a segmentation fault when I turned on ***-O3*** or ***-O2***.

The segmentation happens when it is running a function with **SSE2** macro inside; like

```
_m128i polynomial = _mm_set1_epi8(0x1d)
```

This is only part of the code.

I think I have already eliminate the situation of address alignment on 16 bytes. It's so wired that the -g mode and the ***-O2*** or ***-O3*** mode behaves differently.

Actually, I am not sure the bug is related to SSE2 or not.

I am using ***gcc 4.4.3***.

**Have you encountered the same problem?**

**Or can you gave me some suggestion on how to deal with it?**

Comment: Note that `-g` does not select "debugging mode", it merely adds debug symbols. You can specify both `-O3 -g`, this will produce optimized code with symbols, but there might no longer be a direct 1:1 relation to the source code, which makes it possibly harder to debug (and understand). If you omit `-O3` this implies `-O0`, which produces unoptimized code, which my be easier to read.

Comment: Start the program in a debugger. You will find tons of tutorials on the net. If you are using gcc, `gdb` might be a good choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?bug_status=RESOLVED&resolution=FIXED&target_milestone=4.4.4

Update to a newer version of GCC.